PPP3 first program giving Error message: incomplete type "PPP::Checked_string" is not allowed
I picked up Bjarne Stroustrup's book Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (3rd ed.), but I haven't gotten very far into chapter 2.  I am using Visual Studio 2020 (v143) on a PC.  I did everything to set up a project (Ch2_Fmletter) and include PPP.h, PPP_support.h, and PPP.ixx.  I also did all the project property settings that Stroustrup recommends on his website:

Microsoft C++
When using Visual Studio.

Module files are suffixed .ixx
Set the propeties [sic] of your project. Tab: Project -> Nameofproject.

General properties: Set "C++ language standard" to "latest"
C/C++ general: Scan for additional module dependencies: "yes"




In my project I also include the Header Files PPP.h and PPP_support.h and Resource File (module) PPP.ixx.
From Supporting information from Programming Principles and Practice 3ed instructions unclear, I found information about an error in Stroustrup's PPP_support.h file and made the necessary correction by adding of std:: to the simple_error() function as follows:
    PPP_EXPORT inline void simple_error(std::string s)  // write ``error: s'' and exit program (for non-exception terminating error handling)
    {
        std::cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }

Now I have another bothersome error that is showing up, but the program will compile and run!  There are actually 3 errors that show up, but I think if I get the first one fixed the others will disappear.  The error Code is E0070: incomplete type "PPP::Checked_string" is not allowed.
The source code in my Ch2_Fmletter.cpp file is very simple:
#include "PPP.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your first name (followed by 'enter'):\n";
    string first_name;   // first_name is a variable of type string
    cin >> first_name;     // read characters into first_name
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << "!\n";
}

The module PPP.ixx includes #include "PPP_support.h".
The error Code "E0070: incomplete type," points to the definition of variable first_name: string first_name;  Hovering over first_name, Visual Studio IntelliCode shows me this:

Based on some requests for additional information, I'm showing a screenshot of the Project Build and you can see the listed Errors, in addition to what IntelliCode (IntelliSense) shows:

One of the included header files is PPP.h, and it is reproduced below because it's short.  I don't understand the #define statements, but Stroustrup's comment says that they are "disgusting macro hack"
// PPP.h
import PPP;
using namespace PPP;
using namespace std;

// disgusting macro hack to guarantee range checking for []:
#define vector Checked_vector
#define string Checked_string
#define span Checked_span

The actual source code that is called to do the range checking is in PPP_support.h, the file is found here: Link to PPP_support.h
The difficulty seems to be with class Checked_string.

There might be nothing wrong. Intellicode (aka Intellisense) is known for it's false positives. You can just ignore intellisense errors, as you have already found they don't stop your program from building or running. And if you do not find intellisense useful then you can always turn it off. Save some cycles that way, if nothing else.

Did you #include <string> ? Please show a [mre]. Also, it's named std::string. You can use string if you've done using namespace std; or using std::string;, but don't.

@john, I appreciate your comments!  I added some additional information that may help us determine if there is a problem, or not.

@TedLyngmo, I added some additional information about the header files.  In PPP.h that Stroustrup provides, it appears that the necessary information is included, though PPP.h includes #define string Checked_string

@BryanUnruh I checked those headers (from the website). Seems you are using modules, which unfortunately I don't understand at all. Since modules are a fairly new feature of C++ I would guess that they confuse intellisense and this is a false positive. Maybe you should just fall back on the non-module version #include "PPPheaders.h"
